# Angular: Accessor not doing two-way-binding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to write an accessor component, for an input that has a label associated with it, but I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. When I attempt to do two-way-binding, the value isn't set in the input field even though it is set within the class `MyComponent`.

Why isn't my two-way-binding working? I would expect to see `Something Special` inside the `<input>` that is within `<third-party-input>`. However, the input is empty.

When using `<third-party-input>` on its own, two-way-binding works there, just not when I wrap my component around it.

**Main Component**

```html
<ui-input [(ngModel)]="myValue"></ui-input>
```

```js
export class MyComponent {
  public myValue = 'Something Special';
}
```

**Input With Label Component**

```html
<label>{{label}}</label>
<third-party-input [(ngModel)]="value"></third-party-input>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'ui-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputComponent),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class InputComponent extends AccessorComponent {}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-accessor',
  template: ''
})
export abstract class AccessorComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  protected _value: any;

  public get value() {
    return this._value;
  }

  public set value(val) {
    this._value = val;
    this.onChange(val);
    this.onTouched();
  }

  protected onChange = (_: any) => { };
  protected onTouched: any = () => { };

  public registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  public registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  public writeValue(value: any): void {
    if (value !== undefined) {
      this._value = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In `writeValue()`, shouldn't it be `this._value=value`, instead of `_model` ? If not, could you create a StackBlitz?

Comment: Yeah I changed it, Sorry I cannot create a StackBlitz. I don't have access to `third-party-input` because it is an internal company package.

Comment: I don't think this ever gets triggered `registerOnChange`

Comment: Are you sure about that? Try with the debugger

Comment: I added a `console.log()` and it never runs

Comment: Hmm, what if the input class would not extend the other one? Try to do that and add the registerOnChange method on the InputComponent

Comment: I fixed it I think it was because I didn't have a `name` attribute.

Comment: Makes sense, but it’s strange that you did not receive any error message about that upfront